# How do you color HTML symbols like x's and checkmarks?

Tags: html, dingbats

I would like to make the x's red and the checkmarks green, but confused how to since it's a dingbat HTML code.

```html
      <li><b>HD</b> Available &#10006</li>
      <li><b>Commercial</b> Free &#10006</li>
      <li><b>Unlimited</b> Movies/TV Shows &#10004</li>
      <li><b>Cancel</b> Anytime &#10004</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them in a span and then color the span. Use a class name like `checkmark` and `x`.

See code snippet below:

```css
.x{
  color:red;
}

.checkmark{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><b>HD</b> Available <span class="x">&#10006</span></li>
  <li><b>Commercial</b> Free <span class="x">&#10006</span></li>
  <li><b>Unlimited</b> Movies/TV Shows <span class="checkmark">&#10004</span></li>
  <li><b>Cancel</b> Anytime <span class="checkmark">&#10004</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply wrap each in a **[`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)** tag and give it a `.check` or `.cross` class. Then it's just a matter of adding the **[`color`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/color/)** to each of the classes:

```css
.cross {
  color: #ff0000;
}

.check {
  color: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<li><b>HD</b> Available <span class="cross">&#10006</span></li>
<li><b>Commercial</b> Free <span class="cross">&#10006</span></li>
<li><b>Unlimited</b> Movies/TV Shows <span class="check">&#10004</span></li>
<li><b>Cancel</b> Anytime <span class="check">&#10004</span></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put it in a span tag and add a class like

```
  <li><b>HD</b> Available <span class="coloring">&#10006</span></li>
  <li><b>Commercial</b> Free <span class="coloring">&#10006</span></li>
```

then set color in css like

```
.coloring {
  color:red;
}
```

See sample: https://jsfiddle.net/axz16nqe/1/